# Closing the browser after a time period

Tags: java, browser

Is it possible to close a browser after the expiry time I enter during the browser startup using Java? I have to implement this in Eclipse.

Comment: You (a programmer) have no right whatsoever to close my (an hypothetical end user) browser!  I might have 20 tabs open that have nothing to do with your app.

Comment: BTW - do you control the web page displayed in the browser?  The solution might be to include a Meta-Refresh (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) element in the page.  Note that the WikiPedia entry says in the very first sentence "Meta refresh is a **discouraged** method of instructing a web browser to automatically refresh the current web page or frame after a given time interval..".  (Emphasis mine)  So even this much more innocuous form of what you might be trying to achieve, has been discouraged.  BTW - please post only 1 question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387488/).

Answer (score 0):

Well there has to be a better way but you can create a Runtimeprocess which you distroy after a time Period.

Notice that Killing processes like in this case where you run another program is generally not a good thing to do, as you prevent the OS from ensuring that your Browser doesn't leave anything nasty behind.